# I'm getting confused between two of these sentences

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

> What’s about this support ticket?

This was the question we used inside a product. But some users suggested the below version of the same sentence.

> What’s this support ticket about?

Now I'm getting confused about which one to use. Could you please shed some insights?

Answer (score 2):

*What's about X* is not idiomatic (to me, at least). We say *What about X?* when making a suggestion - "I need some fresh air. What about a walk to the park?"

*What's this support ticket about?"* is a request for information about its purpose and how it works.